# How to load child elements?

Tags: sql, go, go-gorm

I created this structure:

```
type Category struct {
    gorm.Model

    Name        string          `json:"name" gorm:"not null; unique"`
    Parents     []*Category     `json:"parents" gorm:"many2many:category_parent;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:SET NULL;"`
}
```

How to load child elements if I know by parent ID?

Answer (score 0):

You can have another field named `Children` and you can preload it.